# I'm not shouting, I'm just easily distracted

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, editor

This site has a warning about all-uppercase posts, which works for both question titles and post bodies. The problem is that on the body of a post it is triggered prematurely, even by the first character (which is naturally in uppercase).

To reproduce:

1. Enter an uppercase letter in the body of a question or answer.
2. **Look, a squirrel!** (or a chat ping in another tab, or another distraction)
3. As soon as editor's window loses focus, I get yelled at:

[image: boo]

Suggested solution: in the body field match only all-uppercase strings of length 30 or more. Shorter posts cannot be submitted anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok - this check now only fires if at least 30 all-uppercase characters are entered for a post body, 15 for a post title.